# vs2015:vc++ for Linux Development no such file

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I try to use the vc++ for Linux Development plugin to build a linux application on windows. It works for the simple `printf`. But when I try to `include` the local file. I got this error :

```
 mongoose.h: No such file or directory
```

The contents of the project directory :

`test
|---- bin
|---- main.cpp
|---- mongoose
     |---- mongoose.c
     |---- mongoose.h
|---- obj
|---- test.vcxproj
test.sln`

I had tried to add mongoose path to both **property->C++>General->Additional Include Directories** and **property->VC++ Directories**

```
absolute path: D:Code\ForVS\test\test\mongoose

relative path: $(ProjectDir)mongoose
```

But I got the same error. I can't figure out what's the problem, any suggestion? Thank any way.

-----------------------2016.06.22---------------------------------------------

Thanks @Murphy 's comment, it works while using `#include "mongoose/mongoose.h"`.

But I still confuse , it's the **property setting** of vs valid for the *vc++ for Linux Development* plugin ?  If so, how it works ?

Comment: Are you using `#include <mongoose.h>` (incorrect) or `#include "mongoose.h"` (correct) ?

Comment: The `#include "mongoose.h" ` ，but I also had tried #include <mongoose.h>, both don't work .

Comment: Can u try using #include "mongoose\mongoose.h"

Comment: @Sumeet, thank you for your reply! However, it's the same error.

Comment: You better make a habit to use slashes instead of backslashes in includes; try again with `#include "mongoose/mongoose.h"`.

Comment: @Murphy It works now!  Thank you soooooo much!

Answer (score 0):

"$(ProjectDir)mongoose" is Windows style path.

using "./mongoose".